# Conditional formatting on columns

Tags: excel

I have this table:

[image]

I could do this with lots of rules but what I want is:

- If Home Score (Column D) is higher than Away score (Column E) to
  their respective rows make home-score format green
- If it's tie,    make it blue
- If it's less, made it red.

And same thing goes for Column E but in reference to Column D... so you can see where I'm going with this.

Is there a way so I can make it that a row of Home Score/Away score has conditional formatting but not do it individually? I plan on having 300+ rows here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a conditional format to the **whole column** by using a formula that works for the first row, so select whole column D, go into conditional formatting and choose the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option, and then use this formula:

`=AND(ISNUMBER(D1),D1>E1)`

Choose green format

add 2 more conditions for blue and red with `>` replaced by `=` and `<` respectively

Repeat for column E

You don't see it but the formula automatically adjusts for each row so this works for the whole range

Note that the `ISNUMBER` part stops the header row being formatted or blank rows being formatted blue